# Weird positioning of an icon

Tags: css, html, datebox

I have a page (html5, jq, jqm, css), and I'm using [JQM-DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/) plugin

I'm using specifically the FlipBox option. As you can see right on that link, on the right side of the input, there's an icon. The icon shows up in my case ike this:
[image]

Basically this is the HTML:

```
<div id="placeholder1"></div>
<div id="placeholder2"></div>

<label for="mydate">Some Date</label>
<input name="Date1" id="Date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "flipbox"}' /> 


<footer style="background-color: black; color: white; padding: 2em; margin-top: 1em;"><div id="slider"><input id="slide" type="range" min="1" max="90" step="1" value="19" onchange="leslider(this.value, 'lbclassic118', 'lbclassic1990')" /></div></footer>
```

Comment: Please setup a demo of the current output. It is hard to find the problem with your current code and image.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by just ading a `float: right` to the element.